# How Do You Reach Level 101 in Succubox?

Tags: succubox

How do you reach level 101? The game says it requires infinity EXP. Thanks.

Comment: Can you give us a link to this game? After Reading the Answers, i like to know what it looks like :D

Comment: @MarcusRommel I do think, they refer [to this](http://www.glaielgames.com/succubox/).

Answer (score 19):

If you keep "securing" aliens and increase your employee count, eventually all the numbers will grow so large the game can't handle it, and just ends up showing "Infinity". The value necessary is estimated 1.79E+308, which is a bit more than a "fuckloadillion", according to the game.

If you manage your company appropriately, you can reach this number very quickly. Just assign about half your employees to grow your company ("security", space exploration, HR), and the other half to buying and opening loot boxes.

Answer (score 10):

You have to kill something with the True Gun of Thyself. The infinite damage will give infinite overkill xp. This can be done without cheating. The recipe is:

> 1 My Own Merged Soul
>  1 Gun
>  1 Nothingness
>  1 Animosity
>  1 Guilt
>  1 Honesty
>  1 Freedom
>  1 Mojo

A similar recipe for the True Sword of Thyself can be obtained by talking to God, but I believe you already have to be level 101 and have your soul still to talk to Him.

Comment: How do you craft using Nothingness, Animosity, etc? They're conscience variables, not actual crafting ingredients.

Comment: @Voltasalt They will show up as crafting items too, at the button is the list, once you reverse fabricate your own soul.

Comment: Does that also work in hardmode? When hardmode is activated the enemy HP is something like 'f*ckloadzillion' and you can't hurt them anymore.

Comment: @Ullallulloo To be precise, they show up as long as you still have your soul in the list.

Comment: Unfortunately it seems that infinity ATK does nothing against infinity HP. :-(

Answer (score 5):

the simplest way to do it is to open up the Browser's Developer Tools and in the console type

```
data.level.value = 101
```

i have heard people say that when they open the browser's developer tools [they get sent to jail](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/40689575#40689575). as fredley explains [in their comment](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/320055/how-do-you-reach-level-101-in-succubox/320059?noredirect=1#comment455479_320059)

> The jail check is done with this script: https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/blob/gh-page‌​s/index.js, which only checks for the window size changing. It does not trigger if you open devtools in a separate window (undocked).

so keep this in mind if you plan to use this

Comment: The jail check is done with this script: [https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/blob/gh-pages/index.js](https://github.com/sindresorhus/devtools-detect/blob/gh-pages/index.js), which only checks for the window size changing. It does not trigger if you open devtools in a separate window (undocked).

Comment: @fredley ahhhh, my dev tools winder is never docked so that would explain it

Comment: also, it's worth noting that if you open console, you can get out of jail instantly by typing `data.jailtimer = 1`

Comment: Thank you, @Ullallulloo. I seem to get sent to jail whenever I go to another tab.

Answer (score 5):

How to get to level 101? Well you have to go through a number of steps.

1. Craft using two fabricators, to get a real fabricator. Use that on yourself to get My Own Merged Soul. YOU CAN NOT REUSE YOUR SOUL.
2. You now need to get the 6 conscience items

Nothingness

> You get them from opening boxes and finding nothing inside.

Animosity

> You get these by 'employing' others.

Guilt

> You get this from gaining profits from the 'employees' (Unsure)

Honestly

> Give the Dev some money! (Or don't, but answer the question after you click correctly!)

Freedom

> Right click the game, and select 'Inspect'. Go to the Console tab, go to the bottom, and type data.jailtimer=1 (It can be anynumber). The game will send you to hacker jail. At this point, ponder why you are spending so much time on this to the point where you are making/looking at guides online until you get out.

Mojo

> Use a fabricator on a Hat.

Now, craft your weapon, equip it, and play Box Quest 2

Note: You can use Nothingness to enter Hard Mode, to do it you need to craft using Nothingness and

> a soul.

Careful, there is NO GOING BACK

Comment: You get guilt by "securing" people/robots/aliens

Comment: How do I *get* Box Quest 2? I am stuck at level 31 because monsters have infinity HP, and even the *True Gun of Thyself* does nothing. I’ve got several octillion EXP but I need 443 undecillion to level up. At the current rate (even at the current rate increase due to securing aliens) I won’t be able to reach that before the heat death of the Universe (out of game).

Comment: Well my guesstimate was somewhat off (Universe still around, level 36). But I’d still be interested in getting that second box quest. I need those sweet extensions.

Comment: @KonradRudolph Grinding is red herring. You level by assigning most of your *gintilion company to buying and opening boxes.

Comment: @Agent_L Yeah, I figured that out, and reached level 101. At which point the game ended. And I still don’t have Box Quest 2. :-(

Comment: @KonradRudolph Game ends when you buy Fulfillment. If you don't buy it, you eventually get to the Box Quest 2.

Comment: You don't need any hacking to gain freedom. You can get to jail by buying boxes via PayPal and lying about it at first, then few hours later when Cyber Police comes, answer truthfully (that you've lied) and you get jailed. Then wait one hour and voila.